# Group algebra is domain iff doesn't contain nonzero element whose square is 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, group-rings

Let $G$ be a torsion-free group and let $K$ be a field. I have to prove that the group algebra $KG$ is an integral domain if and only if it doesn't contain a nonzero element whose square is equal to 0. Any hints on how to start?

Comment: Is the statement of the condition correct ? An integral domain cannot contain non-zero divisors of zero. Should the condition be "... if and only if it *does not* contain ..." ?

Comment: You're right, my bad! One implication is of course trivial. It's the other direction i'm struggling with.